# Laravel 5: Handle multiple connections and testing

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, phpunit

I have a Laravel 5.4 app which has models pointing to different database connections.

For example, I have `User` pointing to a MySQL database and then `Company` pointing to a PostgreSQL database (using the `$connection` variable).

Now, when I run PHPUnit I'd like the `$connection` variable to be replaced by what's specified in the `phpunit.xml` file, which is a SQLite in memory type of database.

How is that achievable?

Comment: why is the given answer not good for your problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most answers are changing production code, which I don't like.

Since `\Illuminate\Contracts\Foundation\Application` is available in your tests, let's use it!

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Tests\Feature;

use Tests\TestCase;
use App\Models\Company;    

class CompanyFeatureTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * @return void
     */
    protected function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();

        $this->app->bind(Company::class, function () {
            return (new Company())->setConnection(config('database.default'));
        });
    }
}
```

Whenever your `Company` class is called, we give back a manipulated one.
In this one we have changed the `$connection` property.

If you have the following in your `phpunit.xml`:

```
<server name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/>
```

The value of `config('database.default')` will be `sqlite`.

More info about binding can be found here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/container#binding

Answer (score 3):

I'd rather not touch the production code and instead use the service container to create test-specific services.

In this case, if you want all your models to use the same default testing connection:

```
public function createApplication()
{
    $app = require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';

    $app->make(Kernel::class)->bootstrap();

    $fakeManager = new class ($app, $app['db.factory']) extends DatabaseManager {
        public function connection($name = null) {
            return parent::connection($this->getDefaultConnection());
        }
    };
    $app->instance('db', $fakeManager);
    Model::setConnectionResolver($fakeManager);

    return $app;
}
```

(This overrides the `CreatesApplication` trait, you could instead place this code anywhere between when the app is bootstrapped and when the migration command is called).

(Also note this is using PHP 7 inline anonymous classes. You could also define a fake db manager as a separate class).

Comment: This is a good solution. You can put this code in tests/TestCase.php createApplication(). I also edited the fake manager to translate connection names to something else as I wanted to keep my testing connections separate.

Answer (score 2):

Off the top of my head you could move the connection names to the .env file

in your model:

```
public function __construct(array $attributes = [])
{
    $this->connection = env('MY_CONNECTION');
    parent::__construct($attributes);
}
```

in your .env file

```
MY_CONNECTION=mysql
```

in phpunit.xml

```
<env name="MY_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/>
```

Comment: you don't have to move all connection string to the `.env` file. Better check if an if the `MY_CONNECTION` exists. If it does you can overwrite the connection variable.

Comment: You will have potential problem if you cache configuration
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/deployment#optimizing-configuration-loading

"If you execute the config:cache command during your deployment process, you should be sure that you are only calling the env function from within your configuration files. Once the configuration has been cached, the .env file will not be loaded and all calls to the env function will return null."

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned before, you first need to set the connection in each Model. 
So, you setup the connections in the database config file, set the values in the `.env` file and use these in the Model's constructors.

For testing, you could also do this.
Add the testing connection to the `config/database.php` file and then use an overriding env file.

Create an additional env file, name it something like `.env.testing`.

So, in your `.env` file you will have:

```
CONNECTION_MYSQL=mysql
CONNECTION_POSTGRESS=postgress
```

Then in the `.env.testing` file you can have:

```
CONNECTION_MYSQL=test_sqlite
CONNECTION_POSTGRESS=test_sqlite
```

Finally to load this env file when testing, go to `CreatesApplication` trait and update to the following:

```
public function createApplication()
{
    $app = require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';

    $app->loadEnvironmentFrom('.env.testing');

    $app->make(Kernel::class)->bootstrap();

    return $app;
}
```

By using the `loadEnvironemtFrom()` method, all tests that use this trait will load the `.env.testing` file and use the connections defined there.

Answer (score 0):

Like Arturo Rojas wrote in his answer you have to check in the constructor, if the connection variable has to be overwritten:

```
public function __construct(array $attributes = [])
{
    if(App::environment() == 'testing') {
        $this->connection = env('DB_CONNECTION');
    }
    parent::__construct($attributes);
}
```

In your `phpunit.xml` you need these variables (`DB_DATABASE` is optional):

```
<php>
    <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
    <env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/>
    <env name="DB_DATABASE" value="testDatabase"/>
<php>
```

Laravel will then use the sqllite connection from `/config/database.php`